# Weird disk usage on Enterprise Linux

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, administration

I'm little bit worried about this (note the 99% used space in the root):

```
$ df -h
File System                     Size  Used  Free Use% Mounted To 
/dev/mapper/scientific-root      50G   50G  735M  99% /
devtmpfs                        7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           7,8G   80K  7,8G   1% /dev/shm    
tmpfs                           7,8G   89M  7,7G   2% /run
tmpfs                           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md124                       11T  8,0T  2,4T  78% /data
/dev/mapper/scientific-home     408G   41G  367G  10% /home
/dev/md126p1                    497M  213M  284M  43% /boot
```

This situation has arisen unexpectedly as the root has always had ~30% used space. I suspect some unwanted logs have been filling it up. But here's the thing, when I run `du /` even as super user, I can't seem to find 50G worth of files in root.

Do you have any suggestions where to look? Are there any good tools to pinpoint the culprit?

Thanks a bunch,

Peter.

Comment: `lsof +L1` might be a starting point (find files that are deleted but not yet freed because they're kept open by a process). If you've had problems with your mounts recently, it could also be that somebody dropped a few gig in `/data` when it was not mounted. (The mount point is still a directory.) You'd not see those files after mounting `/dev/md124` over it.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz thanks, I've attached the `lsof +L1` output here: http://pastebin.com/YFV4qMmQ. I find theory that `/data` might contain some files as a directory most plausible. I will try unmounting it and listing its files shortly.

Comment: You might get away without unmounting if you bind-mount the root filesystem to a different additional mountpoint. (But I've never done that for /.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the ncdu package, if you can.
(run the `yum clean all` command to temporarily free up some quick space for installing it.)

Once installed run this command as root user:

```
ncdu / --exclude /home --exclude /boot
```

It's like the treesize.exe utility in windows and will guide you to the exact location of the problem

Edit:
For people who would like to see the usage of `ncdu` before installing on a server I recently created a video showing how the ncdu utility can be used with more options for quickfixing disk usage issues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBBuEFxo668

Comment: @OP: you should do well with this, but remember running it as root.

Comment: I ran it as root and it did not find any big directories; got pretty much the same output as from `du`. After reviewing several threads, I believe that the output of `df` might be a bit misleading as to its real meaning. Anyway, I will keep this handy utility around, it's really user-friendly!

Answer (score 1):

You are in a situation where something started to eat space under var or tmp.

Do `# du -sh /* 2>/dev/null`.

Your next GNU/Linux installation will have separate /, /usr, /var and /tmp partitions.

Comment: I have executed this command with the following output: http://pastebin.com/x4R0JLfF The only thing capable of generating ~50GB of space is the `/home` directory which is mounted on separate 500GB drive. So, how do I proceed?

Comment: I edited for you to be able to get complete output (you are missing some items by not using it as root) and for error messages not to be printed. Try again, however using `ncdu` is a very good solution too.